# Adding CustomView on a NavigationBar

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, uinavigationbar

This is my code.

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{

    customView = [[UIView alloc] init];

    UIButton *btnAdd = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(410, -20, 30, 40)];
    [btnAdd setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    [btnAdd setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"oie_815362uTrAOBMX.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btnAdd addTarget:nil action:@selector(addCustomer:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [customView addSubview:btnAdd];

    UIButton *btnJump = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(450, -20, 30, 40)];
    [btnJump setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
    [btnJump setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"oie_8153842yVgkR6XD.jpg"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btnJump addTarget:nil action:@selector(showMenue:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [customView addSubview:btnJump];

    UIButton *btnBarItem = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(300, -20, 100, 40)];
    [btnBarItem setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
    [btnBarItem setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"oie_99342oliBc5Sy.jpg"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btnBarItem addTarget:nil action:@selector(showScanner:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [customView addSubview:btnBarItem];

    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, -10, 30, 30)];
    [imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"oie_972931iW4SHiZU.jpg"]];
    [customView addSubview:imageView];

    UILabel *mainLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, -20, 80, 40)];
    [mainLabel setText:@"Kunden"];
    [mainLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor]];
    [mainLabel setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    [mainLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:18]];
    [customView addSubview:mainLabel];

    [self.navigationItem setTitleView:customView];
}

- (IBAction)showMenue:(id)sender
{
    NewPopUpmenu *options = [[NewPopUpmenu alloc] initWithNibName:@"PopupMenu" bundle:nil];
    [options.view setFrame:CGRectMake(720, 0, 300, 200)];
    [self.view addSubview:options.view];
}
```

Note: Problem is that when i press on my "jump" button it doesn't access it's selector Method (showMenue:).

Comment: and you are sure it isn't called? You origin.x of the popup is 720 and that is not inside the iPhones bounds. So maybe your popup is there but not visible

Comment: it's in Ipad,, second thing is that i am also checking it through debugging, when i press on it it doesn't call the "showMenue" Method.

Comment: Put a NSLog in your `showMenue`(why not `showMenu`- -), check whether the method was called.

Comment: I have already told that method is not called...

Comment: Thanks to "Zaki Shaheen" bhai! the problem was just in initializing frame size.........Thanks everyone who tried to help me.

Answer (score 3):

You are specifying a target of `nil` for each button's target-action pair. If your action method is implemented in the same class, your `target` should be `self`:

```
[btnAdd addTarget:self
           action:@selector(addCustomer:)
 forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
// ...
// Same for other buttons...
// ...
```

Technically, if you specify `nil` for the `target` parameter, the responder chain is searched for an object that responds to the action. The problem you are having could possibly be down to the fact that your `showeMenu:` method isn't the signature that your action is expecting. The action is looking for a method signature that looks like this:

```
- (void)showeMenu:(id)sender;
```

Yet you have specified the `IBAction` return type in the implementation.

Comment: Thanks StuDev! i have checked, but it does make any difference, still it's not working...

Comment: Sir! I have done with all of your suggested solution, but no one is working in a right way. Can you please upload your suggested solution after confirming it in Xcode.

Comment: Thanks to "Zaki Shaheen" bhai! the problem was just in initializing frame size.........Thanks everyone who tried to help me.